# Click function is not triggering even after button is clicked using htmlunit driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am able to click submit button and submit button click is working fine but text entered to add comments is not showing (basically submit button click is working ,but submit button functionality is not triggering ):

DOM:

```
<div _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="d-flex marg-top-2 ng-star-inserted">
    <button _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="marg-start-auto btn btn-secondary" type="button"> Cancel </button>
    <button
_ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="btn marg-start-1 btn-primary" type="button">
        <span _ngcontent-sfd-c33=""></span>
        <adapt-busy-backdrop class="ng-tns-c8-21 ng-star-inserted"></adapt-busy-backdrop>
        <adapt-busy class="ng-star-inserted">
            <ng-component class="ng-tns-c10-23 ng-star-inserted"></ng-component>
        </adapt-busy>
        <span _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="ng-star-inserted">Submit</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is my code :

```
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalizespace(.)='Cancel'[1]/following::span[2]"));
String submitButton = "arguments[0].style.height='auto';arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(submitButton, submit);   
submit.click();
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of just the image of the web elements you are dealing with, can you also add the html code for the comments textarea / submit button?

Comment: <div _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="d-flex marg-top-2 ng-star-inserted">
<button _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="marg-start-auto btn btn-secondary" type="button"> Cancel </button>

<button _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="btn marg-start-1 btn-primary" type="button">
<span _ngcontent-sfd-c33=""></span><adapt-busy-backdrop class="ng-tns-c8-21 ng-star-inserted">
</adapt-busy-backdrop><adapt-busy class="ng-star-inserted">
<ng-component class="ng-tns-c10-23 ng-star-inserted">
</ng-component></adapt-busy>
<span _ngcontent-sfd-c33="" class="ng-star-inserted">Submit</span></button>
</div>

Comment: why are you clicking the span tag? you should be clicking the button tag

Answer (score 1):

You should be clicking the Button tag and not the span tag, please use the below locator:

```
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Submit')]/..")
```

Comment: I tried clicking button tag still i am facing same issue

Comment: Why you have the javascript executor?, use expected condition if you are looking for visibility.

Comment: Code is throwing Element Not Visible Exception so i am using javascript  to make element visible

Comment: What exception it throws? . Try entering the text and click in some frame and then try clicking the submit button ?

Comment: Also i wanna address you i am checking weather button is clicked or not ...as a result button is been clicked and it is moving to next page but event alone is not happening (comment added is not showing in comment section )

Comment: @PremnathReddyvari you are manipulating the DOM!!! so if the test fails still you are forcefully passing it . Imagine the bug is that submit button never becomes visible adn you are doing it through script which is a 'False Negative'

Comment: Some times the text box would be designed such a way that the text entered wouldn't be considered unless user clicks enter or clicks outside the text. Understand the application behavior

Comment: Is the submit button always visible in UI ? and always  in enabled state ? . Or it gets enabled only after user inputs something?

Comment: Okay thanks hide ill check with that and get back to you

Comment: Initially submit button will be disabled once we enter text in textbox thhen submit button will get enabled

Comment: Then give input and pause your test and see whether the button is getting enabled, if not give input, click outside the textbox and pause the test and verify whether it is enabled. Else ask developer what actions will result in submit button getting enabled. Once get it use explicit wait to validate that submit button is clickable

Comment: Thanks for the help hide, code is working fine when i use chrome driver but when i try using html driver i am facing all these issues

Comment: But please avoid using the javascript code, its a bad approach and raise a bug for htmlunit driver if you think its driver related

Comment: @PremnathReddyvari can you try submit.submit() instead of submit.click()

Comment: i tried with submit.submit(); it didn't work hide